# Which Cross-mobile-platform Application and UI Framework?

Tags: android, ios, qt, frameworks, mobile-application

I am building a website in either Rails or DJango, and I also want to write a mobile app for Android and iOS operating systems. (and others, maybe)

What are my options? - i.e. is Qt any good?

Happy to develop the mobile app in C, C++, Python or Ruby.

Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing a Mobile App in **`qt`** (using C++) then you can also convert it in Android app.

Look at [Bringing Qt applications to Android](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/28/necessitas/).

[How to Create and Run Qt Application for Android](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/How_to_Create_and_Run_Qt_Application_for_Android)

Or If you want to write web based application so I think use of [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) (using HTML5, Java Script) is easy to convert in both platform (Android, iOS).

Comment: I've seen a few of those "write mobile apps using HTML and JS" frameworks, but I don't like the idea of them. I am a good C, C++, Python and Ruby coder, so I would like to use those skills.

Comment: Ok, If you are good in c++ then I think go for qt nad then you can convert it to android application (please must visit the link I post). but I don't know how can you use QT application for iOS. Try it.

Comment: There is indeed an iOS port of Qt - not as high profile as the Android port, which is steaming ahead, but it's certainly there. They've a talk at the Qt Developer Days in San Francisco http://bit.ly/qtappstore so it would seem to be moving ahead now :)

Comment: Qt is great, but as long as support for Android and iOS is not official and mature enough, it will cause great deal of headache. Even officially supported mobile platforms (Symbian, Maemo/Meego) have serious problems. For professional development, it's not a framework of choice at it's current state.

Comment: :\ - Well could you recommend something else then?

Answer (score 0):

As a C++ programmer, I have been happy with [Marmalade SDK](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/). With Marmalade you can write in C++ and build for platforms supporting native code including iOS, Android, Symbian, Bada etc. It's intended for games and other high performance mobile applications, but nothing prevents from using it to something else too. It contains decent tools for building 2D UI's, but it's out of the box support for network centered programs is not very good. However, there are various 3rd party libraries available, for example [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting solution. Although a little too far on the expensive side, (I was looking for a FOSS solution), also, missing out of the box networking... I am considering developing a JSON protocol environment with Rails or DJango to facilitate simple native development for all OSs.

Comment: Yes. It is not free. $149 for basic version. They do offer it for free with their Apps Program http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/apps-program , but that's not suitable for your case I think. 

We are using Marmalade for an app that pulls JSON data over HTTP and it works just fine. What I mean with bad networking, is that Marmalade only offers just basic features and I need to write some extra code or to use 3rd party libraries for networking. Nothing special there, but that's considerably amount of more work than with Qt.

Comment: Yeah, but I also have some peripheral hardware interaction, so need more than just JSON parsing.